# scala: inheriting base class from type parameter

Tags: scala

Is that possible to create a type class based on type parameter by inheriting type parameter like in the code below?

I do suspect that this is fundamentally not possible as this is a scala limitation as functional language...

But if possible what I have to change in the code below??

```
class MyInt[T : Numeric]  extends T  {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. You can extend a *class* (traits included), but you cannot extend a *type*, and `T` is a *type*.

Even if it were possible, what would it then mean to have `MyInt[Int]` (which is final), or `MyInt[List[String]]` (which is not a class) ? It would get quite complicated for the compiler very quickly.

Comment: So this is a language limitation and I would assume general limitation for functional programming ???

Comment: It's a language limitation. It doesn't have anything to do with functional programming. I don't know of any programming language that can do exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @PavelOliynyk The intersection of FP and subtyping is small and weird—in most functional languages the question wouldn't even make sense. :)

Comment: well, just checked. It looks like this is not possible in other languages as well. thank you